# Understanding Docker user/uid creation

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

Even after going through lot of materials and SO answers still I'm not clear on docker uid/user usage or implementation.

I understand the below points:

1. An instance of an image is called a container.
2. uid/gid is maintained by the underlying kernel, not by Container.
3. Kernel understand uid/gid number not username/groupname and name is an alias and just for human readable.
4. All containers are processes maintained by docker daemon and will be visible as process in host machine (ps -ef)
5. root (id = 0) is the default user within a container and this can be changed either by USER instruction in Dockerfile or by passing -u flag in docker run

With the above all said, when I have the below command in my Dockerfile, I presume that a new user (`my-user`) will be created with incremented uid.

```
RUN addgroup my-group && adduser -D my-user -G my-group
```

- What happens if I run the same image multiple times i.e multiple containers? Will the same `uid` be assigned to all processes?
- What happens if I add same above command in another image and run that image as container? - will I get new `uid` or same `uid` as the previous one?
- How the `uid` increment happens in Container in relation with the host machine.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When you try to add users in the `RUN` statement, it **does not** create a user on the host. If you do not specify an user with the `USER` statement in your Dockerfile or the `-u` flag while starting container (Assuming the parent Dockerfiles also do not include the USER statement), the container process on host will simple run as `root` user if you have started the docker daemon as root.
So if you create a user using `RUN addgroup my-group && adduser -D my-user -G my-group` it will simply create an user in the container i.e. the user is local to the container. So each instance (container) of that image you run will have the same uid of the user inside the container. **Note: That user will not exist on the host.**

If you want to run the container process on host as another user (which exists on host) then you have 3 options:

- Add a `USER` statement in the Dockerfile
- Use the `-u` flag while running the container
- You can use docker's user namespace feature

I highly recommend understanding the user namespace and mappings by reading this documentation: [Isolate containers with a user namespace](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)

Answer (score 3):

Absent [user namespace remapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/), there are only two things that matter:

1. What the *numeric* user ID is; and
2. What's in the `/etc/passwd` file.

Remember that each container and the host have separate filesystems, so each of these things could have separate `/etc/passwd` files.

> What happens if I run the same image multiple times i.e multiple containers? Will the same uid be assigned to all processes?

Yes, because each container gets a copy of the same `/etc/passwd` file from the image.

> What happens if I add same above command in another image and run that image as container? - will I get new uid or same uid as the previous one?

It depends on what `adduser` actually does; it could be the same or different.

> How the uid increment happens in Container in relation with the host machine.

They're completely and totally independent.

Also remember that you can `docker push`/`docker pull` a built image to run it on a different host.  That will bring the image's `/etc/passwd` file along with it, but the host environment could be totally different.  Correspondingly, it's not a best practice to try to match some specific host's uid mapping in a Dockerfile, because it will be wrong if you try to run the same image anywhere else.

Comment: "Yes, because each container gets a copy of the same /etc/passwd file from the image." No, it's because each container runs the same image that is configured to run as the same *uid*. What's in `/etc/passwd` is irrelevant, the uid doesn't even need to be in there at all.

Comment: What is the best practice for handling user/group ids in a container? I had situation just now where my Docker's user was root with an id of 0 and when I created a file within a filesystem that was mapped with the host, that file was owned by root on the host. The container was spinned up by a user however. I consider that dangerous, at the same time, docker/host user/groups have always been poorly understood, at least by me, and I would like to get better at this because it causes problems in more situations than I'd like count.

Comment: That might be better asked as a separate question.  It's typically advised to not be root within a container, but the specific uid doesn't normally matter.  If your container isn't stateless and has a host-mounted volume it needs to write to, then when you _run_ the container you need to specify a correct uid; nothing gets built into the Dockerfile.  Possibly my answer to [Docker non-root User Best Practices for Python Images?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520801) might give some direction.