# How to resolve default user privilege issue for Dockerfile while i need to run apt-get install for other commands?

Tags: docker

I am using `FROM ubuntu:jammy-20230624`

for my Dockerfile.

When I run a vulnerability scan, I get back a `Default User Privilege` issue. See https://community.microfocus.com/cyberres/b/off-by-on-software-security-blog/posts/docker-security-avoiding-the-root-of-all-evil for details.

WHich I understand to mean that I am using ROOT inside the docker container.

I get that. But in that Dockerfile, I am running other commands such as apt-get install.

Here's the original working Dockerfile

```
# because ubuntu-jammy uses python3 for latest python3.10 and pip3
FROM ubuntu:jammy-20230624

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing

# needed for universe repository
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common build-essential python3.10-venv

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# this is needed for the adding of ppa apt-add-repository
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata

# needed for pip3
RUN add-apt-repository universe

# cause everytime add apt-reposutory need to update to work
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing

RUN apt-get install git -y

RUN apt-get install vim -y

# To ensure pip3 works
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y


# April 2023 pip==23.1.2
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip==23.1.2

RUN apt-get update

# for other standard libraries
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # psycopg2 dependencies
    libpq-dev gcc python3.10-dev


RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get -y clean

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements

# July 2023 pip-tools==6.14.0
RUN pip3 install pip-tools==6.14.0
RUN pip-sync /requirements/base-base.txt /requirements/base-local.txt /requirements/domains-base.txt /requirements/domains-local.txt

COPY . /code/

# Copy the entrypoint to allow DATABASE_URL available
COPY ./docker/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
COPY ./docker/production/django/ /

# RUN for n in entrypoint start-*; do \
#     sed -i 's/\r//' /$n; \
#     chmod +x /$n; \
#     done

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint"]

# copy out /start-web
# start-web executes `migrate` and `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
COPY ./docker/local/django/start-web_django /start-web_django
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-web_django
RUN chmod +x /start-web_django

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

So if i were to add the new user `app_user` i would then need to add it to sudoers and make it passwordless. In other to run the other apt-get commands successfully. Which then defeats the purpose of not using root user.

### Update with Dockerfile example that uses passwordless sudoer

This is the Dockerfile modified to add a `app_user` and make it passwordless sudoer

```
# because ubuntu-jammy uses python3 for latest python3.10 and pip3
FROM ubuntu:jammy-20230624

# we want to RUN for app_user
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends sudo

# Prevent CWE ID 020
# Dockerfile Misconfiguration: Default User Privilege
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash app_user
RUN usermod -aG sudo app_user
# MUST run as root; allow user sudo without passwd
RUN echo 'app_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
# appUser is the backup name for the alternative
USER app_user

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

# needed for universe repository
RUN sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common build-essential python3.10-venv

RUN mkdir /home/app_user/venv

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/app_user/venv

RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

# this is needed for the adding of ppa apt-add-repository
RUN sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tzdata

# needed for pip3
RUN sudo add-apt-repository universe

# cause everytime add apt-reposutory need to update to work
RUN sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

RUN sudo apt-get install git -y

RUN sudo apt-get install vim -y

# To ensure pip3 works
RUN sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y


# April 2023 pip==23.1.2
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip==23.1.2

RUN sudo apt-get update

# for other standard libraries
RUN sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    # psycopg2 dependencies
    libpq-dev gcc python3.10-dev


RUN sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    sudo apt-get -y clean

RUN sudo mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
COPY ./requirements /requirements

# July 2023 pip-tools==6.14.0
RUN pip3 install pip-tools==6.14.0
RUN pip-sync /requirements/base-base.txt /requirements/base-local.txt /requirements/domains-base.txt /requirements/domains-local.txt

COPY . /code/

# Copy the entrypoint to allow DATABASE_URL available
COPY ./docker/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
COPY ./docker/production/django/ /

# RUN for n in entrypoint start-*; do \
#     sed -i 's/\r//' /$n; \
#     chmod +x /$n; \
#     done

# RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint"]

RUN sudo chmod +x /entrypoint

# copy out /start-web
# start-web executes `migrate` and `runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`
COPY ./docker/local/django/start-web_django /start-web_django
RUN sudo sed -i 's/\r//' /start-web_django
RUN sudo chmod +x /start-web_django

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520801/80353, this is effectively the same thing as root. But at least when i run the scan, the scan no longer flags the `default user privilege` issue.

So how do I solve this dilemma?

Comment: Why do you need the user in that place? Can you switch to this user after doing all the apt-get that you need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The security scanner is almost certainly checking what user the image is configured to run as, but it can't check whether any work has been done as root in the Dockerfile.  If you move the `USER` statement to the end of the file (near where you set the image `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`) then the work before this will all happen as root, but the image will still be configured to run as non-root.

```bash
FROM ubuntu:jammy-20230624

# It's okay to create the user really early, you're unlikely to change
# its details and you want to take advantage of layer caching
#
# Create it as a "system" user without a home directory (-r)
# Do not force a specific numeric uid
RUN useradd -r app_user

# You're still doing work as root
RUN apt-get update
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      ...

...

# Specify the alternate user with the rest of the runtime metadata
USER app_user
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint"]
CMD ["./start_web_django"]
```

Do **not** configure passwordless sudo for this user; this all but negates the security benefits you gain against an actual attacker.  Similarly, do not configure a trivially-guessable password for the user.  You shouldn't need to install `sudo` at all: in a Dockerfile you can always switch back to `USER root`, and when you run a container you can specify the `docker run -u` option to set a different maybe-root user.

Comment: Thank you, David. Your answer is exactly what i am looking for. Do yo have a blog or newsletter where you write about Docker related stuff that i can follow?

Comment: i now need to have a /home/app_user and have it be writable as I am using ipdb for localhost debugging. how do i change the dockerfile?