# Is docker need to have the user created first to be use

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 system, and Docker install within it.
So only `root` & `currentUser` available as users inside this system

After that, I create a Dockerfile.
Inside that file I add the new user let say

`RUN adduser someUser`

But `someUser` does not exist on my ubuntu system..
Do I need to have `someUser` inside my ubuntu system or docker can contains it's own user that not even exist inside host machine.

Comment: Related / possible dupe: [Understanding Docker user/uid creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585091/understanding-docker-user-uid-creation)

Comment: I feel you are thinking of Docker wrong. Docker is used to containerize applications without OS dependency. What you need to do is build your container with the right users to access the app. The users on your Ubuntu machine are not mapped to Docker users in almost any instance I have seen in my uses, and I'm not sure of a use case where it seems smart to map docker setup to your running OS directly as it removes portability

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that it's an anti-pattern to try to use specific user IDs in an image to match a specific host setup: you don't want to need to recompile the image just because a different host user is running the container.

Comment: To answer your question: `someUser` does not need to exist on the host machine for you to be able to create the user in your image.

Comment: With all of these comments in mind, if you need help with the architecture, please post your Dockerfile